# Не удается осуществить Concat двух типов объектов под одним интерфейсом

Tags: c#, linq

Имеются 2 типа: `ClientCompany` и `ClientPerson` которые оба представлены в модели и оба реализуют интерфейс `IClient`.

Руководствуясь [вот этим](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579324/how-merge-two-lists-of-different-objects/24579534) вопросом пытаюсь выбрать те и другие классы в один `List<IClient>` лист.

```
List<IClient> ClientsList = db.ClientCompanies.Cast<IClient>() 
.Concat(db.ClientPersons.Cast<IClient>())
.ToList();
```

В рантайме возникает непонятное исключение:

```
System.ArgumentException: "Expression of type 
'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MagnaWPF.ClientCompany]' cannot 
be used for parameter of type 
'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MagnaWPF.ClientPerson]' of 
method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MagnaWPF.ClientPerson] 
Concat[ClientPerson (System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MagnaWPF.ClientPerson],
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MagnaWPF.ClientPerson])' "
```

Comment: Ну, там же есть вариант с `AddRange`, должно сработать. А не работает мне кажется потому, что вы в конкат передаете `IQueryable`, а он хочет `IEnumerable`

Comment: Вместо `Concat` попробуйте `Union`